# DataGrid с привязкой к DataTable: как вместо Null задать значение по умолчанию для новых строк

Tags: c#, wpf

`DataGrid` используется для добавления, изменения и удаления строк данных, загружаемых из базы данных MS SQL. При добавлении новой строки если пользователь заполняет не все текстовые поля в таблицу БД сохраняется в незаполненных полях значение `Null`, что в дальнейшем приводит к проблемам при работе с этой таблицей. Необходимо вместо `Null` сохранять в эти поля пустую строку. Не могу понять как получить доступ к новой добавляемой строке и какое событие какого объекта перекрыть для подстановки вместо `Null` пустой строки. Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть?

```
private void LoadEmployees()
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
    employeesTable = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection connection = null;
    try
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        employeesAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        // установка команды на добавление для вызова хранимой процедуры
        employeesAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertEmployee", connection);
        employeesAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        employeesAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "Name"));
        employeesAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Patronymic", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "Patronymic"));
        employeesAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "Surname"));
        employeesAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Position", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "Position"));
        employeesAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MobilePhone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20, "MobilePhone"));
        employeesAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Rights", SqlDbType.TinyInt, 0, "Rights"));
        employeesAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Login", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "Login"));
        employeesAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20, "Password"));
        SqlParameter parameter = employeesAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Code");
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        connection.Open();
        employeesAdapter.Fill(employeesTable);
        dgEmployees.ItemsSource = employeesTable.DefaultView;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.Close();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dgEmployees">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Code}" Header="Код" Width="60"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Имя" Width="130"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Patronymic}" Header="Отчество" Width="130"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Surname}" Header="Фамилия" Width="130"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Position}" Header="Должность" Width="200"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobilePhone}" Header="Мобильный телефон" Width="130"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Rights}" Header="Права доступа" Width="130"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Login}" Header="Логин" Width="130"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Password}" Header="Пароль" Width="130"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: ну тут самый простой вариант валидацию формы делать которую он заполняет и заставлять его заполнять

Comment: и ваще вы использует wpf и биндаинг а с базой рабоаете через запросы используй EF и все отличчно будет

Comment: самый простой вариант не подходит. Некоторые поля заполнять в принципе не нужно для части записей. Но в них должна быть пустая строка, а не Null

Comment: второй совет тоже к сожалению не подходит. Переделывать практически готовое приложение под EF смысла не вижу.

Comment: Задать в СУБД default value.

Comment: Раз уж вы делаете insert хранимой процедурой, то можно в ней задать замену null на пустую строку. Хорошо бы ещё constraint `NOT NULL` задать.

Comment: Можно триггер на вставку прикрутить... Из разряда бредовых идей...

Comment: constrant NOT NULL не помог. этот вариант я первым попробовал. тогда вылетает с ошибкой по-моему TableAdapter, не помню уже точно

Comment: в идеале нужно отлавливать добавление новой строки в DataGrid и подставлять вместо Null пустую строку. Но вот как подключить пока не могу понять

Comment: default value в СУБД попробую, но что-то мне подсказывает что команда insert заменит это значение на Null и такой способ не поможет

Comment: вариант с заменой в хранимой процедуре insert значения null на пустую строку - неплохой вариант, но что произойдет если затем пользователь начнет менять эту строку? сработает update, а он используется стандартный и соответственно, значения строк Null из DataGrid перепишутся в таблицу базы данных. Так что придется ещё вместо стандартного update хранимую процедуру привязывать.

Comment: _NOT NULL не помог ... вылетает с ошибкой_ - естественно, будет вылетать ошибка: БД не позволит вставить null. И это правильно! Схема БД должна гарантировать корректность данных.

Comment: У `DataTable` есть события `RowChanged`, `RowChanging`, `TableNewRow` - происходят при вставке/изменении строки. Можно в них проверять/менять данные.

Comment: Попробовал использовать валидацию. Прикрутил к классу данных интерфейс IDataErrorInfo, добавил в XAML:                         <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                            <local:RowDataInfoValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
                        </DataGrid.RowValidationRules> Результат печальный, похоже валидация вообще не вызывается.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, с проблемой разобрался, спасибо за подсказку [Alexander Petrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184217/alexander-petrov). При подключенном к DataGrid источнике данных DataTable многие манипуляции непосредственно с DataGrid не работают. Как и не вызываются некоторые события DataTable. Помогла обработка события TableNewRow:

```
    employeesTable.TableNewRow += new
        DataTableNewRowEventHandler(EmployeesTable_NewRow);

private static void EmployeesTable_NewRow(object sender, DataTableNewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row["Name"] = "";
    e.Row["Patronymic"] = "";
    e.Row["Surname"] = "";
    e.Row["Position"] = "";
    e.Row["MobilePhone"] = "";
    e.Row["Rights"] = 0;
    e.Row["Login"] = "";
    e.Row["Password"] = "";
}
```